# Make function pointer from an already declared function

Tags: c++, function-pointers

I have a function declared as `int __stdcall MyFunction(int param, int param);` and I need to get a type of the pointer to the function in a macro or a template when the name is passed as a parameter.

Is this possible in C++ or do I have to rewrite the function signature myself?

Comment: Can you show an example of what you want to do?

Comment: The expression `MyFunction` will automatically decay to a function pointer.  Can you be more specific about what you're trying to do?

Comment: There's an external API (a few headers) that contain function declarations like this. Since I can't link to the API statically, I have to load the functions myself - which means declaring a pointer to them, initialising it and calling it. The pointer declaration part is a bit stupid to do, as I have to go to the headers, check the functions declaration and then rewrite it as a pointer.

Comment: "*external API .. that contain declarations like this*" - like *WHAT* exactly?  Please show some actual code you are having trouble with.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Like the example I provided in my post.
If it's not obvious enough: `int __stdcall MyFunction(int param, int param);`

Answer (score 1):

You can make a type alias for a function pointer (to which it decays, or which is returned by the address-of operator) the following way:

```
#include <iostream>

int MyFunction(int param, int param1)
{
    std::cout << param << " " << param1 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}

using Myfunction_ptr_t = std::decay<decltype(MyFunction)>::type;
// or using Myfunction_ptr_t = decltype(&MyFunction);
// or using Myfunction_ptr_t = decltype(MyFunction) *;

int main()
{
    Myfunction_ptr_t Myfunction_ptr = MyFunction;
    Myfunction_ptr(1, 2);
}
```

This example should rather use the [`auto` specifier](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) (since C++ 11):

```
auto Myfunction_ptr = MyFunction;
```

but that won't help in non-deducible context.

Comment: `auto MyFunction_ptr = MyFunction` will work because auto semantics are manually built into the compiler (since they are derived from templates) but I do not think this is the best practice with `auto`, it should be specified more clearly like this `auto my_function_pointer = &MyFunction;`

Answer (score 1):

Function pointer behaves like every other pointer. It is a memory address which points to some entity (function code in this case). You can save these pointers somewhere and then fetch them in any convenient for your situation way.

For example you can create static map of std::string vs fun. pointer pairs:

```
static std::map<std::string, PTR_TYPE> funMap;
```

After that save pointers to this map and retreive them when needed.

If you don't have pointer yet, probably you speak about exported functions from libraries. In this case look at ldd for *nix-based or somethig simialar for other platform. You will need to search for runtime linker information and find fnction by it's name.

Actually I don't understand why you say you can't link against those functions. Do it in standard way: include header file with such declarations. Use declaration. Linker will do the work for you. Just provide it a path to library with those functions. It will link dynamically to required functions. That's all what you should do. If you don't have such library you need to search for function at runtime manualy with the help of (again) linker at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You could define a `typedef` like below:

```
typedef int (__stdcall *MYFUN)(int, int);
```

Test case:

```
int main() {
  MYFUN f = MyFunction;
  f(2, 3);
}
```

Alternatively, you could use a `std::function` object as bellow:

```
std::function<decltype(MyFunction)> myfun;
```

Test case:

```
std::function<decltype(MyFunction)> myfun = MyFunction;
myfun(4, 5);
```

[**Live Demo**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3410618fddba7554)

Comment: The function is declared in an external API that I cannot modify. And declaring a typedef to it would be rewriting the signature by hand - and I don't want to do that.

Comment: @Displayname you don't have to modify it. You just define a `MYFUN` and assign to it the address of your function.

Comment: But defining `MYFUN` would mean copy & pasting the function arguments and so on from the header, which I don't want to do.

Comment: @Displayname: Sorry, but you will have to do that, if you are not using static linking.

Comment: Usually I avoid typing out the entire type of a function in C++11 and C++14

Answer (score 0):

Got it. `decltype(FunctionName)* pointer;` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `decltype` or `auto`, like the following

```
decltype(&FunctionName) pointer = &FunctionName;
```

or

```
auto pointer = &FunctionName;
```

I avoid manually translating function pointers to types myself in C++11 and C++14 :)